# Updating column in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update column for three rows in sql. However when I run following query, only one row is affected. Can someone help me to see where I am making a mistake? Thank you!

```
update some_table
set date_updated = case some_id
when '7791'   then '2021-10-08 06:59:05'
when '1555'   then '2021-08-26 05:30:54'
when '363201' then '2021-08-31 05:01:45'
end
where some_id = ('7791, 1555, 363201') 
and date_updated between '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-03';
```

Comment: Syntax nightmare. Show us the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `IN` Clause

```
       where some_id in ('7791' ,'1555' , '363201') 
      and date_updated between '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-03';
```

Comment: thank you :) working now, Il accept answer as soon as overflow allows me :)

Comment: No problem :)..

Answer (score 1):

```
update some_table
set date_updated = 
    case when some_id = '7791'  then '2021-10-08 06:59:05'
         when some_id = '1555'   then '2021-08-26 05:30:54'
         when some_id = '363201' then '2021-08-31 05:01:45'
    end
where some_id IN ('7791', '1555', '363201') 
and date_updated between '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-03';
```

Comment: thank you :) working now

Answer (score 0):

you should put IN clause to work properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).